# Set color for future text

Tags: ms-office, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

In PowerPoint, when I am inside a text frame and I have not selected any text and I am then setting the text color, it does not change the color for any currently visible text. It does however change the text color for the text that I will enter next.

I want to achieve the same using the office API.

I have tried `ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 128, 0)`, but this sets all text of the current text frame to this color.

What is the right way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the desired end result? Do you intend to programatically add more text to the string and want to control the color of the new text, or do you want to alter the text box so that when a user adds text to it, the new text appears in a designated color (not sure that's possible)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: I would like to achieve the later: Set the color so that the text that the user types next will have this new color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with something along these lines:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame.TextRange
    With .Characters.InsertAfter(" ")
        .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End With
End With
```

This inserts a space at the end of the currently selected shape's text and sets the space to the desired color. Any text added after that will be the same color as the space character.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, the text input position is not necessarily at the end of the text. It could be anywhere. Also, inserting a space is unacceptable, unfortunately.

Comment: Other than somehow using other code to insert and format text that the user provides via input/dialog box, I'm afraid you're out of luck then.

Comment: There really is no other option? This requirement seems so basic

Comment: To the person who needs a feature, the need for the feature is obvious; less so for others.  Honestly, I've been working daily with PowerPoint and PowerPoint users for almost 30 years now and this is the first time I've run into this request.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But it is very basic, existing functionality in the Office UI. Choose a text color without selecting any text -> Voila. That's why I am wondering and why I am having the feeling that I am missing something

Comment: Unfortunately, not everything in the UI gets implemented in the object model.  If it's important to you, though, put in a request at https://powerpoint.uservoice.com The developers keep a close eye on the site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion